# CKEditor - Automatically removing an empty Anchors

Tags: ckeditor

As I understand the CKEditor is removing automatically an empty Anchors. The problem is that a lot of HTML addons are using empty anchors and they store them in JavaScript after the page is loaded.

e.g. If i like to use AddThis they let me add the next code:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit"></a>
    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
```

And after I change the display from Source to Design the CKEditor is removing all the Anchors.

I know that if I will add   to the Anchors the CKEditor will not remove them but in my case i can not use this.

I found the line that removing the links in the file:
/ckeditor/ckeditor_4.0.1_full_source/core/htmldataprocessor.js
Lines: 536-540

They are adding a htmlFilter rule that removing any empty anchor.
Now, I know i can edit the CKEditor source file and change this but i do not like to
do it because any time that I will upgrade a version i will need to use the same fix so I like to fix it using the CKEditor API.

I found how to add a rule in the next way:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['instanceName'].dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules(
            {
                elements :
                {
                    a : function( element )
                    {
                        //Do what i like to do
                    }
                }
            });
```

The problem is that even when I add a rule for the A TAG its still not overwrite the rule that CKEditor made.

Are there is a way to overwrite there rule or fixing this problem in another way?

Comment: Can you try it with CKEditor 4.1 and then turning the Automatic Content Filtering `true`? That just allows everything and could solve the issue.

Comment: I already try this solution and its not helpful. It leave the "script" but it still removing the "a" tags. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution for this. You'll need to use liquid code parser from shopify (gem liquid), and its really easy to do.  Once you've installed the gem you can do:

```
<%= Liquid::Template.parse(your_ckeditor_content).render({
   code_you_want_untouched => %Q{ html code here }
}) %>
```

Replace your current CKEditor output code with that line.

Then, you now have "code_you_want_untouched" as a variable that you can use within the CKEditor.

You call it like this within your CKeditor content:

```
{{ code_you_want_untouched }}
```

Since the html code isn't coming from CKEditor anymore, it wont strip anything.  The cool part about liquid is you can use as many variables as you want, and you can execute Ruby within the variable code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a random name on the  tags:

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count" name="at_r"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_tweet" name="at_t"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit" name="at_p"></a>
    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style" name="at_c"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is how to add the code without changing/editing the code. I know how to add it but customers that using the system will not know to do it :).

Comment: Maybe you could add a system where your customers can click "add AddThis widget" and you insert the edited code for them?

Comment: Its not only about the AddThis widget its about any widget or external HTML that a user like to insert to his website. Its not static and I can now know witch code  the user will insert. Sometimes its empty tags and some other time it unsupported tags. What I like is that the CKEdtior will stop removing any empty TAG even if its not recognize the tag e.g. <royshoa></royshoa>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the only way I got it to stop deleting the empty tag is adding this to the config.js

```
config.protectedSource.push(/<a[^>]*><\/a>/g);
enterCKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.a = 0;
```

Note: In my cke however, the background images no NOT appear in the editor. They work fine, they just don't show up. I hope its just a bug that will be fixed.